# How is this assembly loading supposed to work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have this NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Common` version `2.6.1` that I use. The assembly in this package is targeting the .NET Standard `1.3`.

I have a .NET Framework desktop console app `net461` that forcefully load all referenced assemblies like this.

```
HashSet<string> visited = new HashSet<string>();

void WalkReferencedAssemblies(Assembly assembly)
{
    if (assembly.IsDynamic)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (var r in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
        if (visited.Add(r.FullName))
        {
            WalkReferencedAssemblies(Assembly.Load(r));
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually I hit this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What I cannot understand but hope to understand is how this is supposed to work. It's not wrong that this happens given that this is exactly what the assembly metadata says BUT I've also learned that `System.Runtime.Loader` isn't used on the .NET Framework desktop CLR. What would be the correct way to deal with this and how would I know that I have to deal with these references in some strange and undocumented way? I came this far by mostly reading up on various GitHub issues spread all over the corefx repo.

Comment: .NET Standard uses many hacks (retargeting, type forwarding for instance), so I assume there are tons of other undocumented. In your case, my guess is that things like `System.Runtime.Loader` are ignored by .NET Framework CLR at application startup (as they are not needed there). So by forcing such to be loaded, you effectively trigger issues that Microsoft does not expect to happen. Why do you have to force load everything in the first place? Use a whitelist to skip such assemblies, or you have to avoid forcing loading completely.

Comment: Could it be an unused reference? The Nuget package no longer provides the missing library because it's not needed but the reference was left behind so when you try to force load it, it breaks. My understanding is that assemblies are only loaded when needed.

Comment: @LexLi this is packaging tool of sorts, I was attempting to get the runtime to pull in all the dependencies given that these are otherwise delay loaded. I need to know what DLLs are actually loaded and how they refer to each other. My idea was based on letting the runtime do that if I forcefully tried to load them... but here I am with just more problems.